# Accessing the state from within a redux-observable epic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am using redux to build a little fusball-manager. Basically it's a page that shows the score of both teams and some buttons to increment them. I have actions like `{ type:"GOAL_UP", team:"red" }` for which the reducer will change the corresponding value (score) in the state.

Now I want to add an epic that whenever it encounters a `GOAL_UP` checks if one of the two teams has won the game. If a team has reached a score of 8, I want it to dispatch a `GAME_WON` action. My problem is that I have to access the state to know the score of each team. I cannot find a way to access the state from within an epic.

Is accessing the state out of scope for redux-observable? If so, how would you solve this problem?

I am thinking about having the new score as a property in the `GOAL_UP` action. Something like this `{ type:"GOAL_UP", team:"red", newScore:8 }`. But somehow this feels wrong. I also have two physical buttons on the fusball-table that are connected with web sockets, which dispatch the `GOAL_UP` action. Since they are not triggered from my ui they don't know about the state.

I could also think of dispatching the `GAME_WON` action in the render function of my ui component if the score of either team is 8. But that feels even more wrong :)

Input is very welcome, Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out the [Accessing the Store's State](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html#accessing-the-stores-state) section of the redux-observable docs.

It describes how, in addition to a stream of actions (the first argument), your epics receive a stream of store states (second argument).

Use `state$.value` to synchronously access the current state. This value will contain your *entire* redux store state.

Note that by the time an action reaches your epic it has **already** be run through your reducers (and any state updated).

```
const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';
const INCREMENT_IF_ODD = 'INCREMENT_IF_ODD';

const increment = () => ({ type: INCREMENT });
const incrementIfOdd = () => ({ type: INCREMENT_IF_ODD });

const incrementIfOddEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.ofType(INCREMENT_IF_ODD)
    .filter(() => state$.value.counter % 2 === 0)
    .map(increment);

// later...
dispatch(incrementIfOdd());
```

---

I would also add that as described, I don't think you need redux-observable or even redux for this--it's rather overkill. Of course, if this is just to get your feet wet and learn, by all means! Just don't want you to think you *need* these complex abstractions for simple things.

Comment: Thank you! I feel somewhat stupid for not having found that.
My app does a lot more than just the score-board. Lets you choose players and gives you stats (at least it one day should :D). I just wanted to have my question as simple as possible. Also, I just realized that I saw your talk about this. So thanks not only for the answer, but for redux-observable :)

Comment: In the latest redux-observable version, this has changed. the second argument is no longer store, but state$ which contains the current version global redux store. So the getState() is no longer needed.

Comment: what's the type of `state$` ?